# Incorrect behavior of data.table when used with sf package

Tags: r, data.table, r-sf

`data.table` does incorrect aggregation when used with `sf::st_union` whereas `dplyr` seems to handle it correctly.  Can someone please explain why `data.table` yields this result?

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp",package="sf"))
nc_DT <- as.data.table(nc)
nc %>% group_by(SID74) %>% summarise(geom = st_union(geometry)) %>% nrow # prints 23 (correct answer)
nrow(nc_DT[,st_union(geometry),by=SID74])  # prints 83 (incorrect answer)
```

Answer (score 4):

If we place it in a `list`, the number of rows will be 23

```
res <- nc_DT[, .(geom = st_union(geometry)),by=SID74]
nrow(res)
#[1] 23
```

You can then easily recover the attributes of the geometry column like this:

```
res <- st_sf(res)
plot(res)
```

Comment: However, the attributes of the geom column get dropped, making it an invalid object; try for instance `plot(res$geom)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @EdzerPebesma .  What attributes should the geom column maintain? AFAICT it should be `class` which should have the value of `c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")`.  This is an issue (mentioned on issues pages of both projects) which will need to be resolved to get `data.table` and `sf` to work together.